# how to create copy of database including tables in windows (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have a database called my_old_db which consists of some tables , now how to create copy of of this Database including tables with new name as my_new_db .

I have tried the following Query

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_db .Tab1 LIKE my_old_db .Tab1; 
INSERT INTO my_new_db .Tab1 SELECT * FROM my_old_db .Tab1;
```

But in my old table i Have nearly 30 tables , taking more time to copy

Dont know the good approach.

Any guidence would be really appretiated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by import/export database 
for that first you need to export database `my_old_db` and then create database `my_new_db` and import the old database `my_old_db`

If you are using phpmyadmin.

For Export :

1. In phpMyAdmin, select your database from the list on the left. (select `my_old_db`)
2. Click on "Export" from the top set of tabs.
3. Select Export Method Quick (default).
4. Click the "Go" button towards the bottom of the page.
5. Save the File in you local desktop.

For Import :

1. Create new `my_new_db` database
2. In phpMyAdmin, select your database from the list on the left.
3. Click on "Import" from the top set of tabs.
4. Click on the "Choose File" button.
5. Browse to your local SQL file and click "Open."
6. Click the "Go" button towards the bottom of the page.